# Feeding custom data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a feedforward neural network which takes $8$ dimensional vector as input and returns a real number. My training data consists of two .txt files, one is set of vectors and the other one is corresponding label (a real number in this case). I am using tensorflow framework to develop and train the network.

```html
N = 8 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
```

What is the tensorflow method to feed the inputs from the training text files in $x$ and $y$?

Comment: This question is quite broad. You should better specify the .txt files format and the way you are training/using the network, but in general you should read the files into some variable and then feed them to network, for example `sess.run(train_op_or_other_tensor, feed_dict={x: loaded_x_data, y: loaded_y_data})`

Comment: Perhaps as an illustration of @BřetislavHájek 's point about the broadness of the question - there is also the Dataset API (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) as an alternative to using `feed_dict`. I'd advocate familiarity with this API as a pretty high priority for using TF effectively 'in the wild' with real data but I recognise that's a personal viewpoint. YMMV

Comment: What format is your data in? Agreeing with @Stewart_R, `tf.data` should be simpler to use than feeding data via `tf.placeholder`s and `feed_dict`s